# How to show pagination in Wordpress for categories?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am displaying my categories on a page. Now, when I have more than x posts, I want to show a pagination to navigate to the next page with the posts.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args = array(
    'cat' => $cat_id,
'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    //Post data
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID());
?>

<li>With some posts</li>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

And then I try to spit out my navigation like this:

```
<?php
function pagination_nav() {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
        <nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?></div>
        </nav>
<?php }
}
?>

<?php echo pagination_nav();
?>
```

But whatever I do, I can't return it. How exactly should I do this? $paged should work, right? I have more than 20 posts, but I can't see my navigation/paging button anywhere.

**Lastly, I tried the code below, yet this does not go to the second page of my query. The URL says /category/categoryname/page/2, but it just sends me to a blank page...**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so let me answer my own question. I solved it by using the same code, but changing the settings (!) in my Wordpress page. When enabling the pagination setting, try to change the default "paginate by 50 posts" to something like "10" or so. That triggers the code to work.